# Search which columns are used in custom queries

Tags: azure, kql

I would like to get the columns that custom queries are using.
For example:

We have table 1:

| Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- |
| Dummy | Dummy |
| Dummy | Dummy |

And the query_custom:

```
Table1
| where Q1 == "dummy"
```

In this example, I would like to retrieve that Q1 is used by query_custom.

Is this possible with KQL?

Comment: Can you explain cleraly?

Comment: @RithwikBojja In Azure Sentinel, we have the Analytics Rules, which some of them are custom queries. Is there a way to search within those specific queries, for certain parts? Like for example, which table is queried or which column. 
I hope that clarifies it, otherwise please let me know.

Comment: @IraklisSkepasianos, you can do this with a python script, I dont think its only possible with KQL

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas Yeah I thought of python, I was wondering if there was a way to do this with KQL, since I can also automate it in Azure. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve required columns using below KQL query:

**`Input:`**

[image]

**`KQL query:`**

```
let y = datatable(Q1:string, Value1:int)
[
    'rithwik',1,
    'bojja',2,
    'rithwik',3,
    'chotu',4
];
y
|where Q1 =="rithwik"
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVGoVLBVSEksAcKknFSNQEOr4pKizLx0HYWwxJzSVEOrzLwSTa5oLgUgUC/KLMkoz8xW1zHUgQgk5WdlJarrGOmgyRtDBZIz8ktK1XVMuGKtuSq5asozUotSFQINFWxtlaBqlQBkYqhlhAAAAA==)

You can also use `contains` in place of `==` , only this type of things is possible in KQL.